# Create a list of the n-th item from each sublist in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python I have a list of lists, say

```
lst = [['2000-01-03', '3.745536', '4.017857', '3.631696'], ['2000-01-04', '3.866071', '3.950893', '3.613839'], ...]
```

I want to create a list of the n-th element of each of these, say

```
newlst_0 = ['2000-01-03','2000-01-04', ...]
newlst_1 = ['3.745536', '3.866071', ...]
...
```

The approach I keep seeing/thinking of is list comprehension to the tune of:

```
[x[n] for x in lst]
```

The problem arises when I try values of `n` other than 0. I keep getting an IndexError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-4ebb08ab526c> in <module>
----> 1 newlst = [x[1] for x in lst]

<ipython-input-33-4ebb08ab526c> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 newlst = [x[1] for x in lst]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

and I can't figure out why. I'm trying to solve this problem in base python, which makes it trickier since I can't just use a data frame from pandas.
Any ideas/hints on what I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.   I don't actually have a problem with your  ```newlst = [x[1] for x in lst]``` when given the lst as described.   Can you post your code as-is?

Comment: I'm guessing one of your sub-lists isn't long enough.

Comment: That seems to be the problem, yeah. I didn't look close enough at my data before trying to do stuff with it, and in my haste, it turns out it was incomplete

Answer (score 2):

Use "unzipping":

```
lists = [list(x) for x in zip(*lst)]
```

`zip(*lst)` is an iterator returning consecutive tuples of the elements of all sublists in `lst`. If you are fine with getting tuples, you can skip the list comprehension:

```
lists = list(zip(*lst))
```

Comment: This is a clean, idiomatic way without having to loop over an `n`.